# Visual Studio switch docker compose file

Tags: docker, visual-studio

In my .net project Im using a docker compose project to handle my docker files.

Inside the docker compose project I have a docker compose file that defines the production environment.

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  api:
    image: ${API_IMAGE}
  networks:
    - internal-network
    - some-other-network
  volumes: 
    - ${API_APP_PATH}/${API_APPSETTINGS}:/app/${API_APPSETTINGS}
networks:
  internal-network:
```

As you can see, it includes some variables that are used for the release process/pipelines.

My problem is that I want to debug and test my application with Visual Studio (by pressing the green "play button")

How can I ignore the default docker-compose.yml and define a docker-compose.dev.yml and use this to start my application via Visual Studio.

I tried multiple things, but each build fails with the following message:

> service "api" has neither an image nor a build context specified: invalid compose project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```xml
<DockerComposeBaseFilePath>docker-compose.dev</DockerComposeBaseFilePath>
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/docker-compose-properties for details.